# plots-3d not applying transformation properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I'm trying to plot a rectangle in 3D, but the following code I've written is giving unexpected results:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,x=1cm,y=1cm,z=1cm]

\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{110}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]

\draw [blue](0,0,0) rectangle (3,3,0);

\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image problem]

Somehow it seems like tdplot_main_coords is not working for the rectangle (but it's working for the axis arrows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rectangle is uniquely defined by two opposite corners in two dimensions, but not in three. If you switch to the relevant plane, you get a transformed rectangle. This can be conveniently done with the `3d` library, which gets loaded by `tikz-3dplot`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,x=1cm,y=1cm,z=1cm]

\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{110}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
 \draw [blue](0,0) rectangle (3,3);
\end{scope}

\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just a quick question: Isn't rectangle also a path? How come regular paths are okey in 3d (like the coordinate lines here) but the situation is different with rectangle?

Comment: @Ali Yes, a rectangle is a path, so is a circle or a parabola, say.  A straight line is well defined by its start and end points, respectively, in any number of dimensions, but a rectangle is only uniquely fixed by two opposite corners only in 2D and after saying what the x and y directions are. Analogous statements apply to circle etc. In any case, the above shows that, if you draw the rectangle in the xy plane, you get the desired result, doesn't it?

Comment: Got it. Thanks.